# Clarification on z-score

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have been reading a Statistics book and they show the following formula for z-score:

$ z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$

And then they explain about the $\mu$ and the $\sigma$ in the formula like this:

> These are the mean and standard deviation of data containing the value
>   x.

But is that so ? I don't think the mean and standard deviation should contain the value `x`.

Answer (score 0):

x comes from some distribution which has a fixed mean and standard deviation, determined before x was generated - you shouldn't be thinking of standard deviations and means of a finite set of numbers here.